# Quarkus Multi-tenant Application

Tags: java, angular, database, hibernate, quarkus

I would like to develop a SaaS application **(multiple tenants**) with [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/) , but I am facing a problem because *Quarkus does not support multi-tenants yet*. **What to do ? What alternative ? Do you have any idea how I can do this ? Do I have to write everything myself ?**

I would like to use Postgresql as the DBMS with the *architecture of a unique database and a separate schema for each tenant*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Quarkus are you using? It seems like the latest Quarkus Hibernate ORM version has exactly what you're asking for:

> Quarkus currently supports the separate database and the separate
> schema approach.

From: https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm#multitenancy

Comment: I'm using the latest version 1.11.0. I hadn't looked well. Thank you very much for the link. I will study the examples and build the architecture of my application for the separate schema. Thank you again for the info.